# No puedo ocultar md o sm usando Bootstrap 5.3

Tags: bootstrap, jsf, primefaces, bootstrap-5, xhtml

estoy tratando de aplicar una clase bootstrap a mi siguiente codigo xhtml. 
Quiero que los contenedores de tamaño md y sm, desaparezcan, por lo que tengo el siguiente test. 
En el codigo está comentado cuales funcionan y cuales no, lo que no logro entender, es por que SM y MD no se terminan de ocultar como las demás. 
Puede que algo este chocando y no me entere. Primfaces también está ahi, pero no se si chocan.

Update: Hasta donde entiendo está chocando con algo. Es un proyecto maven con JSF, no eh descubierto donde y con que choca aún.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:s="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/componentes">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <link
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
    <title>Login Maven</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="frm">
        
        <!-- TEST -->
        <div class="d-none">hide always</div> <!-- No se muestra nunca -->
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block">hide on screens smaller than sm</div> <!-- No se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-md-block">hide on screens smaller than md</div> <!-- No se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div> <!-- Se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block">hide on screens smaller than xl</div> <!-- Se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-xxl-block">hide on screens smaller than xxl</div> <!-- Se oculta -->

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenes un error de sintaxis. El tag `script` se cierra con `</script>`. Si además agregas el tag meta de la respuesta aceptada, debería funcionar correctamente. Si queres evitar que el tamaño de la interfaz se pueda modificar "pellizcando" podes usar: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código XHTML tal cual lo tienes no está considerando las dimensiones del dispositivo, lo cual se ve reflejado al usar Chrome Devtools, para corregir esto tienes que agregar en tu **<h:head>**:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: No te creo, que error más de novato... Muchisimas gracias. Habíamos olvidado completamente este paso durante el desarrollo.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a responderte acá porque no puedo en coments, pero ojo que yo no manejo muy bien **xhtml**.

1- Tus librerías presentan error en la consola. Intente cambiarlas pero fue en vano, el error persistía.

2- La **xs** nunca se va a mostrar porque la estas ocultando, si quieres ocultarla puedes hacerlo por CSS puro como te muestro a continuación:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <style>
        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            .xs-ochoa{
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-xs-block xs-ochoa">hide on screens smaller than xs</div> <!-- No se muestra nunca -->
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block">hide on screens smaller than sm</div> <!-- No se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-md-block">hide on screens smaller than md</div> <!-- No se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div> <!-- Se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block">hide on screens smaller than xl</div> <!-- Se oculta -->
        <div class="d-none d-xxl-block">hide on screens smaller than xxl</div> <!-- Se oculta -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto me muestra los 6 divs y oculta los 6 divs conforme vas cambiando de tamaño. Espero te ayude en algo.

Comment: 1.- Que error en consola ? A mi no me muestra un error. 2.- El XS lo quite, era una redundancia ahora mismo. Es solo d-none ahora en el post. 3.- Puedes hablarme por el chat igual jaja